# Google Map Not appearing even though I'm copying the data directly from the sample code

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm in the middle of learning Google Maps API. It was working perfectly then I changed something and it stopped working. I tried to revise the changes but it didn't help. I even tried copying the code from one of their examples directly from the documentation but It's not working on my computer.

To see if the server was rejecting the API key I put it directly into chrome and it came back with the data.

I've tried their sample script source
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false
and tried it with my own API key. I have no idea what's going wrong.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated. Thank you

This is the example I'm working with right now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Geolocation</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--
    Include the maps javascript with sensor=true because this code is using a
    sensor (a GPS locator) to determine the user's location.
    See: https://developers.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#SpecifyingSensor
    -->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>

    <script>
var map;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  // Try HTML5 geolocation
  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                       position.coords.longitude);

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        map: map,
        position: pos,
        content: 'Location found using HTML5.'
      });

      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(true);
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleNoGeolocation(false);
  }
}

function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
  if (errorFlag) {
    var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
  } else {
    var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
  }

  var options = {
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
    content: content
  };

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
  map.setCenter(options.position);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm new to stack overflow. Should I delete the question?

Comment: Not necessarily.  It may get closed, but someone might find it searching for the same problem as you and get pointed to the answer.  I would only close it if it gets down voted and hurts your "reputation".